# How do I determine the number of unique derived types in an array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I have the following classes

`Customer` Class

```
abstract class Customer
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public double balance;
}
```

class `NormalCustomer`

```
class NormalCustomer: Customer
{
}
```

class `SubscriberCustomer`

```
class SubscriberCustomer:Customer
{
    public int LandMinutes;
    public int MobileMinutes;
}
```

If we create an array of `Customers`

```
Customer[] customers = new Customer[100];
customers[0]=new NormalCustomer();
customers[1] = new NormalCustomer();
customers[2] = new SubscriberCustomer();
customers[3] = new NormalCustomer();
customers[4] = new SubscriberCustomer();
```

The question is how do I know how many object in the array are `NormalCustomers` and how many object in the array are `SubscriberCustomers`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method

```
customers.OfType<NormalCustomer>().Count()
```

You will need to import `System.Linq` namespace with a using directive:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Aleksey's answer - but if you want alternatives:

```
// Result is a sequence of Type/Count objects
var groupedByActualType = customers.GroupBy(
    x => x.GetType(), (type, values) => new { Type = type, Count = values.Count() });
```

Or:

```
var normal = customers.Count(c => c is NormalCustomer);
var subscribers = customers.Count(c => c is SubscriberCustomer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ and group them:

```
var groupedCustomers = customers.GroupBy(c => c.GetType()).ToList();

foreach(var customer in groupedCustomers)
{
   Console.WriteLine(customer.Key.Name + ", count: " + customer.Count());
}
```

https://ideone.com/fz93H6

Ensure you have included the [`System.Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.111).aspx) namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer[] customers = new Customer[100];
            customers[0] = new NormalCustomer();
            customers[1] = new NormalCustomer();
            customers[2] = new SubscriberCustomer();
            customers[3] = new NormalCustomer();
            customers[4] = new SubscriberCustomer();

            int normalCount = 0;
            int subscriberCount = 0;

            foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            {
                if (customer != null)
                {
                    string customerName = customer.GetType().ToString();
                    // get name without namespace
                    customerName = customerName.Substring(customerName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    switch (customerName)
                    {
                        case "NormalCustomer":
                            normalCount++;
                            break;
                        case "SubscriberCustomer":
                            subscriberCount++;
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    abstract class Customer
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public double balance;
    }
    class NormalCustomer : Customer
    {
    }
    class SubscriberCustomer : Customer
    {
        public int LandMinutes;
        public int MobileMinutes;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work, it's quite messy and doesn't really conform to SOLID.